# React/Semantic UI add call to action on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Using `Semantic-UI` / `ReactJS` want to add `onClick` function on `button`, but when I add, it call function on `input` click too, but I want to add only on `button`

```
handleClick= (e) => this.setState({ click: true});
...
  <Input
    action={{
      color: 'teal',
      labelPosition: 'left',
      icon: 'cart',
      content: 'Checkout',
    }}
    actionPosition='left'
    placeholder='Search...'
    defaultValue='52.03',
    onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
```

*Result:*

```
<div class="ui left action input">
  <button class="ui teal icon left labeled button">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="cart icon"></i>
    Checkout
  </button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." value="52.03" />
</div>
```

See demo result [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input/), in this page, serach `You can pass a Button props object.` to find example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your passing an object in your action attribute to create your button you can simply add an `onClick` property

```
<Input
  action={{
    color: "teal",
    labelPosition: "left",
    icon: "cart",
    content: "Checkout",
    onClick: handleClick
  }}
  actionPosition="left"
  placeholder="Search..."
  defaultValue="52.03"
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-gyk4m?module=%2Fexample.js

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the onClick propery inside action.

```
action = {{
    color: 'teal',
    labelPosition: 'left',
    icon: 'cart',
    content: 'Checkout',
    onClick: handleClick
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `Input` and also `handleClick` on it, not `Button`, you need to use `Input` and `Button` separately, then call function on button like this:

```
<Input
  placeholder='Search...'
  defaultValue='52.03',
/>

<Button color='teal' content='Checkout' icon='cart' labelPosition='left' onClick={this.handleClick} />
```